# Delta IV Heavy trans-lunar injection mass

Tags: the-moon, payload, delta-iv-heavy

What is the mass capacity for the Delta IV Heavy for a trans-lunar injection? Or is there a way to take its capacity to GEO or LEO and substitute it into a formula which would bring the approximate capacity for a trans-lunar injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [John Schilling's calculator](http://www.silverbirdastronautics.com/LVperform.html), Delta IV Heavy should be able do about 9.8 tons to TLI (defined as a 185km perigee, 400000km apogee Earth orbit).

Because of the [nonlinearity of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) and wide range of launcher performance characteristics, there's not a general rule for estimating TLI capacity from LEO or GEO capacity, unfortunately.